# How to pass value of cell of datagridview to another form

Tags: c#, winforms

There are two forms.

In the first form there is a textbox and a picture box.

When the picture box is clicked it opens the second form which contains a datagridview.

What I want is: when I click on the cell of a datagridview its value should be shown in the textbox of first form.

I do not want to create object of first form in second form because data of grid views has to be passed to multiple forms

Comment: You need to use an instance of the form (same one that is running).  See my code at following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: can you add some code please?

Comment: OMG, not again. Not again a question about passing values between forms. Please!

Comment: Thanks for the answer jdweng

Comment: Thanks for the answer jdweng but in my project there are many forms like first form that contains text box and picture box and one second form that contains datagrid view..In your solution you have created the object of second form in first form and uses that .but i want generic solution

Answer (score 0):

I would define a delegate in the second form and assign a method from the first form to it.

In Form 2:

```
public Action<string> DataSelectedCallback;

private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (DataSelectedCallback != null)
    {
        var cell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
        DataSelectedCallback(cell.Value)
    }
}
```

In Form 1:

```
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.DataSelectedCallback = cellData =>
    {
        // do something with cellData
    };
form2.Show();
```